# Python - counter reset routine

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am building a semi automated lighting system which uses this script to turn it on i.e. a motor turns a mechanical dimmer for 1.2 seconds -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

Motor1A = 16
Motor1B = 18
Motor1E = 22

GPIO.setup(Motor1A,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1B,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1E,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(Motor1A,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Motor1B,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)

sleep(1.2)

GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

I also have another two scripts which fade the lights up or down in increments of 0.15 seconds. Here is one of them -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

Motor1A = 16
Motor1B = 18
Motor1E = 22

GPIO.setup(Motor1A,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1B,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1E,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(Motor1A,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Motor1B,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)

sleep(0.15)

GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Assuming that the lights are faded either up or down prior to turning off I need a way of determing the light setting at that particular moment i.e. if the lights have been faded two stops for example then a script needs to reverse the motor for 0.9 seconds to return to 'zero'.

In an attempt to solve this I began to look at counters with the idea that if each 0.15 seconds increment represents the integer '1' for example then starting from the number 8 i.e. 8 x 0.15 = 1.2 (the system when initially on) I should be able to work out where I am at at any one time.

To implement this I tried this script -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import with_statement
with open('num.txt','r+') as f:
    counter = str(int(f.read().strip())+1)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(counter)
```

which works fine from the command line but won't run when I place it in the 'increment' script above.

So now I am a bit stuck and wondering if this is even the right direction anyway for solving the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Btw the incremental script is triggered by pressing a button on a remote i.e. one button press = one increment.

Comment: `counter = str(int(f.read())+1)` works for me if `num.txt` exists and contains a number already.

Comment: You might want to look at using something more hands-off, like [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

Comment: @ffledgling - OK thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: @esfy - I ammended my script to `counter = str(int(f.read())+1)` however it still will not run from with the 'incremental' python script using the subprocess module